# Load Models Three.js GLTFLoader Syntax error JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, three.js, parceljs

I learn how to use Three.js by following the tutorial on discoverthreejs.com.

I have no worries about creating meshes and geometry via three.js

The problem is when I want to load models coming from blender or others.

I use blender 2.8 to create my model and export it as a .glb file. I test the file with a gtlf viewer and everything works as expected.

[image]

But as soon as I want to import my model with Three.js to my website, I get this error:

[image]

[image]

I thought it came from my model, I tried to export it in gltf or glb: same error.

I downloaded another model available on the web: same error.

I use parcel.js if it helps.

```
{
  "name": "cedric_grvl",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html --host 192.168.0.37 --open Firefox"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^9.0.2",
    "postcss-modules": "^1.4.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "three": "^0.111.0"
  }
}
```

Everything is test in my index.js.

Here is how I call Three.js: (all is good here)

```
*index.js*

import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
```

Here are the function for Three.js (tutorial)(all good here)

```
*index.js*

// these need to be accessed inside more than one function so we'll declare them first
let container;
let camera;
let controls;
let renderer;
let scene;
let mesh;

function init() {

  container = document.querySelector( `[data-js="canvas"]` );

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF );

  createCamera();
  createControls();
  createLights();
  createMeshes();
  createRenderer();

  // start the animation loop
  renderer.setAnimationLoop( () => {

    update();
    render();

  } );

}

function createCamera() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    35, // FOV
    container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, // aspect
    0.1, // near clipping plane
    100, // far clipping plane
  );

  camera.position.set( -4, 4, 10 );

}

function createControls() {

  controls = new OrbitControls( camera, container );

}

function createLights() {

  const ambientLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(
    0xddeeff, // sky color
    0x202020, // ground color
    5, // intensity
  );

  const mainLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 5 );
  mainLight.position.set( 10, 10, 10 );

  scene.add( ambientLight, mainLight );

}



function createMeshes() {

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );

  const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x800080 } );

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

  scene.add( mesh );

}

function createRenderer() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
  renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight );

  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

  renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
  renderer.gammaOutput = true;

  renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

// perform any updates to the scene, called once per frame
// avoid heavy computation here
function update() {

  // Don't delete this function!

}

// render, or 'draw a still image', of the scene
function render() {

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

// a function that will be called every time the window gets resized.
// It can get called a lot, so don't put any heavy computation in here!
function onWindowResize() {

  // set the aspect ratio to match the new browser window aspect ratio
  camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;

  // update the camera's frustum
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // update the size of the renderer AND the canvas
  renderer.setSize( container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight );

}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

// call the init function to set everything up
init();
```

Problem is here maybe I do something wrong.

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

const url = "./assets/models/test.glb";

// Here, 'gltf' is the object that the loader returns to us
const onLoad = ( gltf ) => {

  console.log( gltf );

};

loader.load( url, onLoad );
```

I've been thinking about a problem with the path
I tried :

```
'/src/assets/models/test.glb'
'assets/models/test.glb'
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Thx for your time

Comment: Can you please verify with the dev tools of your browser whether the `glb` file is actually loaded or not?

Comment: It seems to be loaded, I added a screenshot @Mugen87

Comment: Can you please share the `glb` in this thread?

Comment: I don't think its come from the glb files, because Itried with an other one which not coming from my blender app

Comment: I tried to export the files in a gltf format. It does the same

Comment: Can you share your code/project as a github repository?

Comment: Yes of course. Thx for your time

Comment: https://github.com/CedGrvl/ced_grvl @Mugen87

Comment: Although the console says `Thonker.glb` has been loaded, the content of the response is actually a HTML file. So it's seems something goes wrong in the way you are hosting your app. Maybe you run into: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1080

Comment: That was it, I have to copy the glb files. parcel-plugin-asset-copy does the job @Mugen87 Thx you very much

Answer (score 0):

In your code import the model like this

```
import MODEL from './assets/Horse.glb'
```

Model will be the path to the glb asset then use it to load like this:

```
loader.load( MODEL, function ( glb ) {
    that.scene.add( glb.scene );
  }, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error( error );
});
```

Comment: I am getting: @parcel/core: No transformers found for _assets/Horse.glb_.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [discourse.threejs.org](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltf-glb-threejs-bundled-with-parcel/34784/3)

```
const parcelPath = new URL('./public/models/hands.glb', import.meta.url);
         
loader.load( parcelPath.href  , function ( glb ) {
        that.scene.add( glb.scene );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hey write the path like this :

```
let gltf = new GLTFLoader();
gltf.load(
    'PATH....',(model_scene)=>{
      scene.add(model_scene.scene) 
   }
)
```